# Specific ORDER BY FIELD in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have searched google, and found a lot of ways to sort in `ng-repeat`, but I did not find any information for my situation. I also don't have code to supply, I do not really know if it is possible.

This is the problem. I have an array of `Items` and all of the `Items` have a `group`. The groups that are available are `['rare', 'uncommon', 'common']`. Now I use a `ng-repeat`, but they come all spread apart. I want to order them by, Rare first, Uncommon second, and Common as last. **Secondly** all the `Items` have a `price`, and within each rarity, I want them also to be ordered by `price`.

Now in this example, I can just order by `group` desc alphabetical, but in my other situations this will not work. I am really looking for a method to order by strings.

In MySQL this could be achieved by:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'Banana', 'Apple') DESC, price DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [official documentation of orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

> expression
>
> A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> function: Getter function. **The result of this function will be sorted using the <, ===, > operator**.
>
> string: [...]
>
> Array: An array of function or string predicates. **The first predicate in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent, the next predicate is used.**

(emphasis mine)

So, you first need a function that allows comparing your groups, with 'rare' coming first, then 'uncommon', then 'common':

```
var orderedGroups = ['rare', 'uncommon', 'common'];
$scope.groupComparator = function(item) {
    return orderedGroups.indexOf(item.group);
}
```

You don't need anything for the price, since it's a field of the item, and orderBy can simply take the field name. So you can just do now

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:[groupComparator, 'price']"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the documentation but I am still new to Angular, and don't quite understand how to map this together. Would it be possible to add a small code example? I tried `ng-repeat="item in Items | orderBy:[rarity:['rare', 'uncommon', 'common']]"`, but this is not it.

Comment: Wow nice so simple ! Thanks I got it working in seconds.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I worked a little further and stumbled upon another problem with sorting, maybe you got an idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170648/getting-ng-table-to-sort-my-data

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom filter like this:

```
app.filter('sortByGroup&Price', function($filter) {
  return function(input) {
    var result = [];
    var rare = $filter('filter')(input, {group: 'rare'});
    result.push($filter('orderBy')(rare,'price');
    var uncommon = $filter('filter')(input, {group: 'uncommon'});
    result.push($filter('orderBy')(uncommon,'price');
    var common = $filter('filter')(input, {group: 'common'});
    result.push($filter('orderBy')(common,'price');
    return result;
  };
});

ng-repeat="item in Items | sortByGroup&Price "
```